# Login form not giving any errors and not actioning script

Tags: php, mysqli

Having a bit of an issue with a simple login process on a html form with a php script. So, I have created the register user part which adds the user to the database as expected so I know it exists.

[image]

The issue is now trying to log the user in, I am using the `password_hash();` method to encrypt the password. I am wondering in my script how I decrypt the password? The biggest is that when I submit the form it gives me no errors back at all despite there being an argument to do so.

I have error reporting on and nothing is coming back, I know it is posting as I did a simple `var_dump()` on `$_POST` and it shows me the expected results, here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('header.php');

var_dump($_POST);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userlogin']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userpassword']);

    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userlogin='$username' and userpassword='$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
            header("location: home.php");
        } else {
            $error="Username or Password is invalid";
        }
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userlogin">
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="userpassword">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

** MORE INFO **

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Venture</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<?php include('../db.php'); ?>

<h1>Header</h1>
<hr />
```

Comment: You don't decrypt it, you encrypt whatever is passed to you in the same way and compare both encrypted values.

Comment: When logging in users, you should not be decrypting the password from the database and matching it with the one provided via POST. Instead, take the one provided via POST, hash that the same way you did when you registered the user and compare that result against your database.

Comment: You can't decrypt hashes. Hashes are a meat grinder. Cow goes in, hamburger comes out. You cannot take that hamburger and turn it back into a cow.

Comment: @Blake  thanks guys that makes more sense to me I will look into how that can be achieved, the biggest concern I have is that the scrip isnt even doing anything? Is that because I have nothing set for the password like I do in my register script?

Comment: If you need to verify password that was hased in your way you need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: i have a code to show you it , but is that ok if i used PDO ? @Dan

Comment: @Laith sure i am open to suggestion

Comment: cool just give me 5 mins

Comment: @Dan Are you going to use email and username to log in ? or just username ?

Comment: @Dan just posted an answer

Comment: @Laith I just use username plus the password is using the `$userpassword = password_hash($_POST['userpassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` to encrypt the passwords in the registration script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i will link a code that i use it to login to my CP , is so slimier to yours but with few changes like :

- Used PDO to execute Query and to fetch username and password from your database .
- Prevented my code from SQL injection . How ? i will explain in the code .

Edit : added this line to verify the entered password with stored password :

```
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password_user, $password);
```

This is the Code :

```
    <?php 
        session_start();
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username   = "root";
        $password   = "your database password";
        $database  = "your database";
            try {
                    $conn =new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                }

    if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
        {

            $User_name = $_POST['userlogin'];
            $password_user = $_POST['pass'];

            $FetchUserData = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userlogin = ?");
            $FetchUserData->execute(array($User_name));
            $FetchedData = $FetchUserData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($FetchedData)
                    {
                        $password = $FetchedData['userpassword']; // Save the fetched password inside variable 
                        $isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password_user, $password); 

                        if( $password_user == $isPasswordCorrect )
                            {
                                $_SESSION['login_user']=$User_name;
                                header("location: home.php");
                            }
                        else 
                            {
                                echo "Password is wrong":
                            }

                    }
            else
                {
                    echo "User is not exist ";
                }

        }



?>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Login</h1>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userlogin">
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn-login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

- As you can see , i used PDO To execute and Fetch the data from the database , a simple Query just like the one in your code can do the job but its to danger , it can be broken so its not prevented from getting hacked , some people can use SQL injection . Whats SQL Injection ?

> SQL injection is a code injection technique, used to attack
>   data-driven applications, in which nefarious SQL statements are
>   inserted into an entry field for execution (e.g. to dump the database
>   contents to the attacker).

You can read more about it from here : [SQL INJECTION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

What i did to the code so it can be secured ?

I did this :

```
$FetchUserData = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userlogin = ?");
$FetchUserData->execute(array($User_name));
```

Try not to enter direct parameters to any query you create , use the way that i showed you it will do the job .

hope this code help you .

Comment: Fantastic answer, all that I get though no matter what is that it tells me my user does not exist!?

Comment: I also created a a user with the username 'test' and the password as 'test' I still get the alert telling me the user does not exist?

Comment: Aswell, when I leave and visit the page it tells me 'something went wrong'

Comment: yea first can you show me your db php page , i want you to change things in it

Comment: Its the usual `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);` with the variables being the correct parameters

Comment: yea well i will give you a code to replace with your db code and try to see if it works : `$servername = "localhost";
     $username   = "root";
     $password  = "";
                    $database  = "yourdatabase";

     try {
       $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
       // set the PDO error mode to exception
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      }
     catch(PDOException $e)
      {
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
      }`

Comment: and i updated the code : toke away "something went wrong" part . make sure that the query is matching your database fields ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122860/discussion-between-dan-and-laith).

Comment: Ok so I switched the db con file to to what you suggested and it has given me the white screen of doom

Comment: @Dan edited the code , now the issue that you had with the password and the one that we saw should be fixed , test it and let me know .

Answer (score 0):

When logging in users, you should not be decrypting the password from the database and matching it with the one provided via POST. Instead, take the one provided via POST, hash that the same way you did when you registered the user and compare that result against your database.

```
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userlogin']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userpassword']);

    // Make sure to set the value of $hash to the one in the database for the user.
    // You can grab your user by the userlogin value
    if (password_verify($password , $hash)) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
        // continue your user validation
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid password.';
    }
```

Comment: That seems to have killed the script altogether...?

Comment: Did you replace the `bcrypt` function with whatever you used to hash passwords when you register users?

Comment: I use `$userpassword = password_hash($_POST['userpassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` in my register script and switched it to `$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` with what you provided

Comment: This is now outputting the HMTL but I am in the same boat still where by when submitting the script does nothing at all.

Comment: Your issue could also be with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. I have found this function to be unreliable at times depending on your php and server configuration.

Comment: I also removed `mysqli_real_escape_string()` but still nothing happens no message from the else statement or any errors outputting?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to timing attacks. There is a reason PHP has the `password_*` API to prevent people from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: @PeeHaa Timing attacks are a separate issue than the one above. I was simply working with the code provided by the user.

Comment: OP is using `password_hash` so no you are not. And adding vulnerable code when somebody asks a question about passwords is negligent at best.

Comment: @PeeHaa bcrypt was a rough example as per my comment. Anyway, thanks for the input. I updated my answer.

Comment: You are missing the point. This is still vulnerable to timing attacks (i.e. [you are using the `password_*` API wrong](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)).

Comment: @PeeHaa I looked at the api and I'm not sure how I am misusing it. Can you explain? -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Click the blue text in my previous comment to find out the correct function to use to verify passwords.

Comment: @PeeHaa Good call. Updated my answer.